# Beginner - Springboot weather program

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, weather-api

I'm learning Java and SpringBoot. Trying to make a web app to check the weather. I'm using API from https://openweathermap.org/api.

I do not know how to retrieve data from API (JSON). Could someone tell me something?

```
    public String connectAndResponse(String url) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getResponseCode()==200 ? connection.getInputStream() : connection.getErrorStream()
    ));

    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

I have already processed JSON on a string but I do not know how to use JSON to use spring boot (it would work on a form where the locale is typing).

Answer (score 0):

From **[Spring documentation "Consuming a RESTful Web Service"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)** :

> This guide walks you through the process of creating an application
>   that consumes a RESTful web service.

First, you will have to define your model. In this case, it is `Quote` and `Value`.

Then, you will be able to call your API.

Here's the example :

```
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
        log.info(quote.toString());
    }

}
```

`RestTemplate` will automatically transform JSON from API into Java object.